# Is it possible to do IE automation using Python?

Tags: python, vbscript, automation

Since my last question was extremely broad, I figured I'd break it down.

So the question is... by using Python, can I have a script automate opening IE and automatically have it enter data into a field using a variable that would be gathered by the username that logged in?

I have it done in VBS for the most part, but can it be done in Python? Here is what I have in VBS:

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

call WshShell.Run("http://myurl/", 1, false)

WScript.Sleep 1500
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "username"
WScript.Sleep 250
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 250
WshShell.SendKeys "password"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

WScript.Quit()
```

**PROBLEMS**

As you can see I have to tab between fields which I would like to not have to do. I also would like to not use sleep timers as different PCs may load at different speeds causing issues with Sendkey being executed too early.

So again, can all this be done in Python? If not, this code will work temporarily, I just need help figuring out how to gather the username from the currently logged in user. (Username and password are the same, making them the same variable) **Ex:** A possible for loop to access the folder name without the path? (C:/Users/username)

If you'd like to see in context what my end goal is, here is the link to my old question that was definitely too broad but just for reference: [Entire program written in steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359571/automatically-loading-ie-and-gathering-login-credentials-based-on-a-specific-fol/31359700#31359700)

Comment: To answer your question, Yes, it can be done in Python. As for why you are getting downvoted, I am guessing it's because you have not shown any attempt to solve your problem using python. The way it currently reads, you are asking for code conversion from VBS to python and stackoverflow is not a code conversion site or service.

Comment: Ok thank you that's all I needed to know. I wasn't looking for a conversion. If it wasn't possible in Python I was going to ask for help with my code. Thanks!

Comment: Very well. This forum can be quite hostile to newbies. I just upvoted your question :)

Comment: @Shiva Please don't do this. The only effect it has is that it encourages bad questions. We already have more than enough of those.

Comment: Actually another effect it has is that I'll continue to use it. And now that Shiva has told me whether it's possible, my next questions won't be nearly as large if I have any at all.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers At the same time, we cannot scare away legitimate programmers by down-voting their questions without giving any sort of explanation as to why. I was traumatized when this happened to me on SO when I got started. Almost never came back to this site. So the least I can do to oxy, whose reputation score of 8 shows he is new here, is to  give him a possible explanation for down-votes and upvote it so he is not so much downvoted he leaves and never comes back.

Comment: @Shiva you're spot on, I did almost leave. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try automation frameworks with python bindings like  selenium for these tasks.